# Perl Regex: separate by spaces and tabs but avoid spaces on filenames?

Tags: php, regex, parsing, command-line, pcre

I'm parsing the output of a command line application that looks like the following:

```
0644    1276317623781623132132      Crappy little message        filename.txt
0644    1276317623781623132132      Crappy little message        My File.txt
0644    1276317623781623132132      Crappy little message        Crazy FILE.txt
```

Sometimes fields are spaced by tabs, sometimes by spaces. How can I write a Regex to separate the fields? I was using preg_split with [\s]+, but this messes up the message and file names. I'm pretty lost here.

Comment: Which command line application is it? Can it make the output easier to parse?

Comment: I don't think that's relevant.

Comment: split on `[\s][\s]+` (Assuming that none of those crappy messages or filenames have *two* spaces.)

Comment: Can you do substring? Since the input is so nicely formatted. Have you tried specifying the limit in preg_split, so that you can customary parse the file name and message part?

Comment: BTW, some commands have `-print0` option that makes parsing easier. (Parsing filenames any other way just isn't safe; null is the only character not allowed in them.)

Comment: You might be SOL ;-)  If you have cases where columns are separated by a single space, AND a single space can appear in the middle of a field, how can you tell the difference??  **IF** there is some logic that you can bring to bear on this difference then you will have to encode it into your regex.  Do you have this extra information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to build a more specific regex to match:

For example, assuming the last one is a tab, you can hit with:

You can split using

```
preg_match('/^([0-9]{4}).*([0-9]{22})[\s]*([^\t]*)[\s]*(.*)$/', $string, $aMatches);
```

You can vary that to match your needs if the example above fluctuates. Or the last is not a tab but a bunch of spaces, then look for the required number of spaces etc etc.